# Bar-chart Bars Bunching up with use of Brush

Tags: d3.js, brush

I have a `barchart` which uses a `scaleband()` for letters on the x-axis.

There is a brush which scales and pans the main chart. However, when using the brush, there is some odd behaviour. In the left corner there are extra bars displaying on top each other. It seems as though some of the bars not in brush selection are displaying as close to the x-axis origin as possible. This must be a default x-position for bars that have no x-position value.

[image]

Here is the full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style type="text/css">
  body {
    font-family: avenir next, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .zoom {
    cursor: move;
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
  }

  .axis {
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
    stroke: #888;
    font: 10px avenir next, sans-serif;
  }

  .axis>path {
    stroke: #888;
  }
</style>

<body>
</body>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  /* Adapted from: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172 */

  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 90,
      left: 50
    },
    margin2 = {
      top: 230,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 50
    },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = 300 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

  var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1), //removing rangeRound no effect
    x2 = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]);

  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0),
    xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2).tickSize(0),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0);

  var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([
      [0, 0],
      [width, height2]
    ])
    // .on("start brush end", brushed);
    .on("brush", brushed);

  var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 20])
    .translateExtent([
      [0, 0],
      [width, height]
    ])
    .extent([
      [0, 0],
      [width, height]
    ])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

  svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

  focus.append("text") // yAxis label
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
    .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
    .attr("dy", "1em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Distance in meters");

  svg.append("text") // xAxis label
    .attr("transform",
      "translate(" + ((width + margin.right + margin.left) / 2) + " ," +
      (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + ")")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Date");

  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "zoom")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(zoom); //see var zoom above

  focus.append("g") //append xAxis to main chart
    .attr("class", "axis x-axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g") //append yAxis to main chart
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(yAxis);

  // d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
  //   if (error) throw error;
  var data = [{
      "date": "A",
      "distance": "1100"
    },
    {
      "date": "B",
      "distance": "1500"
    },

    {
      "date": "C",
      "distance": "2000"
    },
    {
      "date": "D",
      "distance": "2500"
    },
    {
      "date": "E",
      "distance": "1975"
    },
    {
      "date": "F",
      "distance": "3000"
    },
    {
      "date": "G",
      "distance": "2100"
    },
    {
      "date": "H",
      "distance": "2100"
    },
    {
      "date": "I",
      "distance": "3300"
    },
    {
      "date": "J",
      "distance": "2000"
    },
    {
      "date": "K",
      "distance": "2100"
    },
    {
      "date": "L",
      "distance": "2000"
    },
    {
      "date": "M",
      "distance": "2000"
    },
    {
      "date": "N",
      "distance": "2000"
    },
    {
      "date": "O",
      "distance": "3000"
    },
    {
      "date": "p",
      "distance": "1975"
    },
    {
      "date": "Q",
      "distance": "3000"
    },
    {
      "date": "R",
      "distance": "2100"
    },
    {
      "date": "S",
      "distance": "2100"
    },
    {
      "date": "T",
      "distance": "3300"
    },
    {
      "date": "U",
      "distance": "1500"
    },
    {
      "date": "V",
      "distance": "2100"
    },
    {
      "date": "W",
      "distance": "2000"
    },
    {
      "date": "X",
      "distance": "1800"
    },
    {
      "date": "Y",
      "distance": "2200"
    },
    {
      "date": "Z",
      "distance": "3000"
    }
  ]
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.distance = +d.distance;
      return d;
    },
    function(error, data) {
      if (error) throw error;
    });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.distance;
  })]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());

  //********* Main ar Chart ****************

  var rects = focus.append("g");
  rects.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)"); //the element to be clipped
  rects.selectAll("rects")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return "lightblue";
    })
    .style('stroke', 'gray')
    .attr("class", "rects")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.date);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.distance);
    })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.distance);
    });

  // //********* Brush Bar Chart ****************

  var rects = context.append("g"); //draw bar chart in brush
  rects.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
  rects.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")

    // var focus_group = context.append("g");
    // focus_group.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
    //
    // var brushRects = focus_group.selectAll('rect')
    //   .data(data);
    //
    // //********* Brush Bar Chart ****************
    //
    // var brushRects1 = brushRects.enter();
    //
    // brushRects1.append('rect')

    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return "lightblue";
    })
    .style('stroke', 'gray')
    .attr("class", "rectss")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x2(d.date);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y2(d.distance);
    })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height2 - y2(d.distance);
    });

  context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis x-axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
    .call(xAxis2);

  context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .call(brush)
    .call(brush.move, x.range());
  // });

  //create brush function redraw scatterplot with selection
  function brushed() {
    if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom

    // get bounds of selection
    var s = d3.event.selection,
      nD = [];
    x2.domain().forEach((d) => { //not as smooth as I'd like it
      var pos = x2(d) + x2.bandwidth() / 2;
      if (pos > s[0] && pos < s[1]) {
        nD.push(d);
      }
    });

    x.domain(nD);

    // d3.select("rects").remove();

    focus.selectAll(".rects")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.distance);
      })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.distance);
      });

    focus.select(".x-axis").call(xAxis);

    // var e = d3.event.selection;
    // var selectedrects = focus.selectAll('.rects').filter(function() {
    //   var xValue = this.getAttribute('x');
    //   return e[0] <= xValue && xValue <= e[1];
    // });

    svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
      .translate(-s[0], 0));
  }

  function zoomed() {}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "odd" bars you see on the left of the graph are the bars which are not in the range of the selection anymore but are still displayed because data is not updated correctly*.

When updating the data based on the brush event, we need to both update the set of bars to display and remove previous bars which shouldn't be displayed anymore.

The brush update can be performed this way:

```
focus.selectAll(".rects")
  // removes previous bars
  .remove().exit()
  // modifies the set of bars to display:
  .data(data.filter( function(d) { return nD.indexOf(d.date) > -1 }))
  .enter().append("rect")
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return "lightblue";
  })
  .style('stroke', 'gray')
  .attr("class", "rects")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  ...;
```

where old bars are removed this way:

```
focus.selectAll(".rects").remove().exit()
```

and the new set of bars corresponding to the selection is determined by filtering the original set:

```
.data(data.filter( function(d) { return nD.indexOf(d.date) > -1 }))
```

---

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 90,
    left: 50
  },
  margin2 = {
    top: 230,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  height2 = 300 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var data = [{
    "date": "A",
    "distance": "1100"
  },
  {
    "date": "B",
    "distance": "1500"
  },

  {
    "date": "C",
    "distance": "2000"
  },
  {
    "date": "D",
    "distance": "2500"
  },
  {
    "date": "E",
    "distance": "1975"
  },
  {
    "date": "F",
    "distance": "3000"
  },
  {
    "date": "G",
    "distance": "2100"
  },
  {
    "date": "H",
    "distance": "2100"
  },
  {
    "date": "I",
    "distance": "3300"
  },
  {
    "date": "J",
    "distance": "2000"
  },
  {
    "date": "K",
    "distance": "2100"
  },
  {
    "date": "L",
    "distance": "2000"
  },
  {
    "date": "M",
    "distance": "2000"
  },
  {
    "date": "N",
    "distance": "2000"
  },
  {
    "date": "O",
    "distance": "3000"
  },
  {
    "date": "p",
    "distance": "1975"
  },
  {
    "date": "Q",
    "distance": "3000"
  },
  {
    "date": "R",
    "distance": "2100"
  },
  {
    "date": "S",
    "distance": "2100"
  },
  {
    "date": "T",
    "distance": "3300"
  },
  {
    "date": "U",
    "distance": "1500"
  },
  {
    "date": "V",
    "distance": "2100"
  },
  {
    "date": "W",
    "distance": "2000"
  },
  {
    "date": "X",
    "distance": "1800"
  },
  {
    "date": "Y",
    "distance": "2200"
  },
  {
    "date": "Z",
    "distance": "3000"
  }
]

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1), //removing rangeRound no effect
  x2 = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
  y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
  y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0),
  xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2).tickSize(0),
  yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0);

var brush = d3.brushX()
  .extent([
    [0, 0],
    [width, height2]
  ])
  // .on("start brush end", brushed);
  .on("brush", brushed);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 20])
  .translateExtent([
    [0, 0],
    [width, height]
  ])
  .extent([
    [0, 0],
    [width, height]
  ])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "focus")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "context")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

focus.append("text") // yAxis label
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
  .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Distance in meters");

svg.append("text") // xAxis label
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + ((width + margin.right + margin.left) / 2) + " ," +
    (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + ")")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Date");

svg.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "zoom")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .call(zoom); //see var zoom above

focus.append("g") //append xAxis to main chart
  .attr("class", "axis x-axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

focus.append("g") //append yAxis to main chart
  .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.distance; })]).range([height, 0])).tickSize(0));


data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.distance = +d.distance;
    return d;
  },
  function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;
  });

x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.date;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.distance;
})]);
x2.domain(x.domain());
y2.domain(y.domain());

//********* Main ar Chart ****************

var rects = focus.append("g");
rects.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)"); //the element to be clipped
rects.selectAll("rects")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return "lightblue";
  })
  .style('stroke', 'gray')
  .attr("class", "rects")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.distance);
  })
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.distance);
  });

// //********* Brush Bar Chart ****************

var rects = context.append("g"); //draw bar chart in brush
rects.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
rects.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")

  // var focus_group = context.append("g");
  // focus_group.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
  //
  // var brushRects = focus_group.selectAll('rect')
  //   .data(data);
  //
  // //********* Brush Bar Chart ****************
  //
  // var brushRects1 = brushRects.enter();
  //
  // brushRects1.append('rect')

  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return "lightblue";
  })
  .style('stroke', 'gray')
  .attr("class", "rectss")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x2(d.date);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y2(d.distance);
  })
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height2 - y2(d.distance);
  });

context.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis x-axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
  .call(xAxis2);

context.append("g")
  .attr("class", "brush")
  .call(brush)
  .call(brush.move, x.range());
// });

//create brush function redraw scatterplot with selection
function brushed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom

  // get bounds of selection
  var s = d3.event.selection,
    nD = [];
  x2.domain().forEach((d) => { //not as smooth as I'd like it
    var pos = x2(d) + x2.bandwidth() / 2;
    if (pos > s[0] && pos < s[1]) {
      nD.push(d);
    }
  });

  x.domain(nD);

  // d3.select("rects").remove();

  focus.selectAll(".rects")
    .remove().exit()
    .data(data.filter( function(d) { return nD.indexOf(d.date) > -1 }))
    .enter().append("rect")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return "lightblue";
    })
    .style('stroke', 'gray')
    .attr("class", "rects")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.date);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.distance);
    })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.distance);
    });

  focus.select(".x-axis").call(xAxis);

  // var e = d3.event.selection;
  // var selectedrects = focus.selectAll('.rects').filter(function() {
  //   var xValue = this.getAttribute('x');
  //   return e[0] <= xValue && xValue <= e[1];
  // });

  svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
    .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
    .translate(-s[0], 0));
}

function zoomed() {}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: avenir next, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.zoom {
  cursor: move;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.axis {
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
  stroke: #888;
  font: 10px avenir next, sans-serif;
}

.axis>path {
  stroke: #888;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body></body>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

---

<sub>*: Bars which not part of the range anymore, when their associated `x` position is computed via the new `x.domain`, becomes `undefined`, which is interpreted as `0`. That's why they are displayed at the left of the graph.</sub>

Comment: Brilliant, that works perfectly now thanks. I knew they were bars from outside the selection but I couldn't remove them. I see it now. Thanks very much for your help with this. Much appreciated

Comment: Not sure why the y-axis is displaying values between 0 and 1. But I suppose that needs to be a separate post.

Comment: You can modify the way you set the y-axis this way (Your axis needs to know the domain of your data): `focus.append("g").attr("class", "axis axis--y").call(d3.axisLeft(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.distance; })]).range([height, 0])).tickSize(0));`.